# Cancel button reset Html input file

Tags: html, angular, typescript, input

I am working on an Angular 8 Application. I have a scenario where a user can select a file and display the selected file in a container with File Name and size. If a user want to delete the file and replace it with another file, the user should click cancel which will reset the container and input element too.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   {{fileName}}
</div>
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile02" 
       (change)="onSelectFile($event)" accept=".xlsx, .xls, .csv" #fileUpload>
<span class="input-group-text sidebutton" id="">Cancel</span>
```

.ts

```
onSelectFile(event: any): void {
  this.selectedFiles = event.target.files;
  let name = event.target.files
  this.previews = [];
  this.fileName = this.selectedFiles[0].name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Include This Button:

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
```

The button will reset all input.